# nutch 1.2 solr 3.1 bad request issue

Tags: solr, nutch

I have crawled a site successfully using NUTCH 1.2 .Now I want to integrate this with solr 3.1 . Problem is when I am issuing command $ bin/nutch solrindex localhost:8080/solr/ crawl/crawldb crawl/linkdb cra wl/segments/* an error occurs. I am attaching my nutch logs

Please help me to solve this issue

Bad Request

request: //localhost:8080/solr/update?wt=javabin&version=2 at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CommonsHttpSolrServer.request(CommonsHttpSolrServer.java:436) at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CommonsHttpSolrServer.request(CommonsHttpSolrServer.java:245) at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.AbstractUpdateRequest.process(AbstractUpdateRequest.java:105) at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer.add(SolrServer.java:49) at org.apache.nutch.indexer.solr.SolrWriter.close(SolrWriter.java:75) at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexerOutputFormat$1.close(IndexerOutputFormat.java:48) at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:474) at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:411) at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:216) 2013-07-08 17:38:47,577 ERROR solr.SolrIndexer - java.io.IOException: Job failed!

Comment: 400 bad request means something failed on the Solr side. In a recent case for me, I had this problem because I had turned on the metadata parser, but never updated my Solr Schema.xml file to include the correct fields that plugin expected to index data to. What does your solr log say. For instance i have Solr installed with Tomcat 6 so my log is at /var/log/tomcat6/